# Running Android application

Tags: android, emulation, nexus-5

When I run a program with Android Studio with emulator, Nexus_5_API__21_x86 runs and I don't see environment Android in emulator; my emulator stops in Android logo while booting.

Please help me.

Comment: Are there any error messages that it throws at you?

Comment: No,only stop in android logo in starting my emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep on lowering the RAM values and starting it up again.